# Is there a way to automatically resolve and start an autofac startable in module?

Tags: c#, .net, autofac, ioc-container

I am using autofac IStartables to load config, e.g.

```
public class MyConfig : IMyConfig, IStartable
{
  public string configValue { get; private set; }

  public void Start()
  {
    configValue = ... // Load from config file
  }
}
```

And then in the bootstrapper module, register it like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<MyConfig>().As<IMyConfig>().As<IStartable>().SingleInstance();
```

This all works well when using autofac to resolve the config in constructors, but sometimes I want to use some of the config values in the bootstrapper module itself. I have managed to get it working by using:

```
var config = new MyConfig();
config.Start();
// now we can use config.configValue
```

However this 2 step initialisation doesn't seem very clean - is there a better way of doing this with autofac?

Comment: I don't understand what exactly is the problem. When you say "but sometimes I want to use some of the config values in the bootstrapper module itself" what do you mean by that?

Comment: The instances registered in the bootstrapper module need to behave differently depending on config values, so I need to use the config values in the module.

Comment: Can you give some solid example of what you're trying to achieve (with some code)?

Comment: Using the config in the module is not the problem so I haven't included that code, it doesn't seem right to have to manually call config.Start() which is the code snippet at the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `Start()`. It will be called automatically when the container is built. That's the whole point of `IStartable`.

http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/startup.html

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, as they say on the link you posted: "Start will be called [...] the first time the container is built." However, I want it to be usable in my bootstrapper module, and I think autofac only builds the containers when they are used from constructors. I will need to revisit this and create a sample app as it's clear my descripton is not clear enough...